# Automatically set value in database during data insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

My website is built in Laravel and if I add an item to the website, the URL is automatically set in a certain format.  I like the format.  What I am wondering is how can I edit the INSERT code so that the URL is set when I insert multiple rows of data into the database via file import (I am using a file import script)?  The URL is not in the file itself.  Everytime a row is inserted into the database, the URL should automatically be set for that particular item.

The Add Item form on the website uses the following code to automatically set the URL:

```
            $find=array(",","."," ");
            $replace=array("","","-");
            $titleurl = str_replace($find,$replace, $sname);
              $url='schools/'.strtolower($titleurl);
              $check=schools::where('url', '=', $url)->first();
              if(count($check)>0){
                   return redirect()->back()
                ->with('message', 'Looks like there is a similar school. please review post');
              }
```

Example of what my INSERT code looks like:

```
      $query = "INSERT INTO schools (
            id,
            name
       ) VALUES (
        '$id',
        '$name'
         )";
```

Comment: any examples ???

Comment: examples of ......what?  What am I supposed to show you?  What it looks like when I add an item using the form?

Comment: What it looks like when I add an item using the form? yes

Comment: hint: you can also use Laravel's str_slug function to "clean" your url (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-slug) your code will be cleaner

Comment: and you could use Laravel's validator to check if the URL is unique.